# Python Requests get() - parameters with spaces

Tags: python, get

I'm using the `get()` function to pull data from an API, but one of the parameters has a space in it.

```
parameters = {
    "f": "json",
    "lang": "en",
    "STATION_NAME": "HAMILTON+A",
    "LOCAL_YEAR": "2000",
    "limit": "1000",
    "offset": str(offset)
}

response = requests.get("https://api.weather.gc.ca/collections/climate-hourly/items", params=parameters)
```

When I reach the end of the data pulled with the `STATION_NAME` parameter it starts pulling data from other weather stations which match either `HAMILTION` or `A`.

Is there anyway to make the param more strict to ensure it does not pull unwanted data? This issue only seems to happen for the parameter that has a space in its value.

Comment: This sounds like a detail in the implementation of the API by `weather.gc.ca` rather than a python-requests problem

Comment: Why put the `+` in the name? I would try with `"STATION_NAME": "HAMILTON A"`

Comment: @JonSG since the params put the parameter into a URL, that's why I put a `+`  to account for the space. I'd originally tried `"STATION_NAME": "HAMILTON A"` but it results in completely incorrect results

Comment: Don't do that. `requests.get()` automatically encodes the parameters for you, so it will convert space to `+`. If you put `+` in the parameter, it will encode it to produce a literal `+` character.

Comment: @Barmar but without the `+` it starts pulling from `WATERLOO WELLINGTON A` instead of `HAMILTON A` and `HAMILTON RBG CS` like it currently is with the `+` included? I can't figure out why it's not `request.get()` is not encoding it properly?

Comment: How about `"CLIMATE_IDENTIFIER": "6153194",` rather than `"STATION_NAME": "HAMILTON A"`?

Comment: @JonSG yes that would definitely work!! Kind of have to add a dict to make it more user friendly but thanks!!